# Why console.log in puppeteer page.evaluate doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, es6-promise, puppeteer

Got this function from another developer and i'm trying to debug it.
It's a web scraper based on puppeteer.
But from some reason i can't console.log inside.

Can someone please point me to what am i'm missing here?

```
const getArticles = async (page) => {
  return await page.evaluate(() => {

  console.log('in page.evaluate')
//not printing anything in the console

    const products = document.querySelectorAll(".thumb-link")
    const formated = Array.from(products).map(x => x.href)
    console.log(22, formated)
    return Promise.resolve(formated.filter(x => x))
  });
}

let newArticles = await getArticles(page)
```

Comment: it works, but in your browser. not on your node console. check your browser console

Comment: So you were able to find it in your browser right?

Comment: yes i do , thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to see the browser's console log:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text()));
```

Comment: Nice, it works! But what i don't understand is, if it's in the browser, then how can i do document.querySelectorAll and save the results into a variable that exist in Node.js?

Comment: @yoni349 then you need to use [`evaluateHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) which can handle returning in-page objects. If only need to bring elements to Nodejs use [`page.$$`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageselector-1)

Comment: thanks for the info. but the 'querySelectorAll' actually works. i get a 'JSHandle@array' on 'console.log'. but then it gets resolved into the data i need out of 'page.evaluate'. I was actually asking on the last comment how does it work? if 'page.evaluate' is running in the browser, then why 'querySelectorAll' inside of it returns the data i need? i guess maybe since at the end it if i return the data to the object called the 'page.evaluate'?

Comment: @yoni349 I'm not following, `querySelectAll` works _because_ it's being evaluated in the browser context. it's similar to browser console. as long as the data is serializable you can return it from (or pass it to) browser context using `evaluate`. the `href`s you're collecting are serializable, but the actual elements are not.