# why can't I use previously defined variables inside a $eval?

Tags: puppeteer

In this example I have error that user and password are not defined.

```
await page.$eval('input[type="email"', el => el.value = user);
await page.$eval('input[type="password"', el => el.value = pass);
```

also if I put a `console.log()` inside a `eval`, it is not shown in the `nodejs` `terminal`.

```
    const dataTabla1Temp =  await page.evaluate(()=>{
      console.log("hi");
    })
```

why does this happen and how can I fix it?

```
    const user= "user";
    const pass = "password";
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await  page.goto("xxxxx", {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("error loading url", err));
    //user and password does not exist
    await page.$eval('input[type="email"', el => el.value = user);
    await page.$eval('input[type="password"', el => el.value = pass);
    await page.click("#_submit");
    .
    .
    // console.log is not showed
    const dataTabla1Temp =  await page.evaluate(()=>{
      console.log("hi");
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function)

Comment: I believe you're asking two questions: (1) [How can I pass variable into an evaluate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088351/how-can-i-pass-variable-into-an-evaluate-function) and (2) [Why console.log in puppeteer page.evaluate doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479692/why-console-log-in-puppeteer-page-evaluate-doesnt-work). The fundamental misunderstanding in both cases is that `evaluate()` runs code in the browser console, not Node, so it doesn't have access to Node variables and doesn't send logs to the Node process. Both actions need to be done explicitly.